# Langton's Ant is unbounded?

Tags: automata

Suppose I have a grid of black/white squares (not necessarily all white).
How can I prove that [Langton's ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) is unbounded when it runs on this initial condition?

It seems as though the way to go about this is noting that if it were bounded, it's periodic and achieving a contradiction by looking at the neighbours of the initial square. However, this approach hasn't worked so far for me.

Comment: So why don't you explain what Langton's ant is?  Do you honestly believe everyone who could answer this question here knows about it?

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that the unboundedness of Langton's ant is known as the Cohen–Kong theorem or the Cohen–Kung theorem.

Comment: Hint: if a configuration was periodic, there would be a cell that the ant visits, but doesn't visit any cell to the north or east of it.

Comment: A simple proof is given [here] (http://www.angelfire.com/ms/tushar/chtheorem.html).  I've just read through it quickly, but it feels correct.

Answer (score -2):

Using [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) Turn the lattice into a single dimensional array, iterate the "Langtons ant wave equation" and observe that a) Langtons ant is created and b) $\Psi_\vartriangle$ is indeed a 1D array and look at the variable $k$, a plot of this can be seen in my group on linkedin [104 unbounded highway](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6513491081454198784) since this highway is a recurrence relation you can show by telescoping the index $t$ into the index $k$ into the array $\Psi_\vartriangle$ is unbounded in the limit as long as the size of the lattice $E^2$ is taken to the limit of infinity (Calculus).

Graham

Comment: This could be a fine answer if more details were given and you used MathJax to render the variables appropriately.